# Is there a way to specify a selector from a function or variable in LESS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I have a situation where I need to specify the nth instance of a given selector AND all following siblings. So I have this:

```
td:nth-child(n + 2)
{
    width: 125px;
}
```

But I do a lot of this, with different selectors and different offsets, and repeating the `nth-child(n + offset)` is tedious and obscures the intent of the code.

I would prefer to do something like this:

```
.self-and-siblings(@selector; @offset)
{
  ~'@{selector}:nth-child(n + @{offset})';
}
```

and then invoke it like this:

```
.self-and-siblings('td', 2)
{
    width: 125px;
}
```

But this doesn't compile. Is it possible to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 1):

Less doesn't have any *true* functions that can return values. Also a mixin can output content only within selector blocks (either a selector of its own or the parent selector). In your case there is only a string print but it is not assigned to any property (or) present within any selector block.

For your case, you can write a very simple mixin like below and use it:

```
.nth-child-mixin(@offset, @props){
  &:nth-child(n + @{offset}){
    @props();
  }
}
td{
  .nth-child-mixin(3, {
    color: red;
  });
}
td{
  .nth-child-mixin(5, {
    color: blue;
  });
}
```

The above `nth-child-mixin` takes the `offset` and the properties that should be assigned as inputs. The properties is a [detached ruleset](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) which is then called from within the nth-child selector block. The compiled CSS output will look as follows:

```
td:nth-child(n + 3) {
  color: red;
}
td:nth-child(n + 5) {
  color: blue;
}
```

---

A more comprehensive mixin would be the below as you can pass it the multiplier for `n` also.

```
.nth-child-mixin(@multiplier, @offset, @props){
  &:nth-child(@{multiplier}n + @{offset}){
    @props();
  }
}
td{
  .nth-child-mixin(2, 5, {
    color: blue;
  });
}
```

The compiled CSS in this case would be the following:

```
td:nth-child(2n + 5) {
  color: blue;
}
```

---

I feel using detached rulesets make it more clearer but if you want the mixin to just output a selector, you could make the mixin definition as follows. The only drawback is you may occasionally run into scoping issues when you need more than one such block within same nesting.

```
.nth-child-mixin(@multiplier, @offset){
  @sel: ~":nth-child(@{multiplier}n + @{offset})";
}
td{
  .nth-child-mixin(1, 3);
  &@{sel}{
    color: red;
  }
}
td{
  .nth-child-mixin(2, 5);
  &@{sel}{
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

For example if you want to write two nth-child selectors like below within same `td` nesting then it wouldn't produce the expected output due to scope, lazy-loading etc.

```
td{
  .nth-child-mixin(1, 3);
  &@{sel}{
    color: red;
  }
  .nth-child-mixin(3, 5);
  &@{sel}{
    color: red;
  }
}
```

and that would push you into using anonymous selector boxes like in below sample to solve the scoping issues (these hacks are just terrible).

```
td{
  & {
    .nth-child-mixin(1, 3);
    &@{sel}{
      color: red;
    }
  }
  &{
    .nth-child-mixin(3, 5);
    &@{sel}{
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hahaha @Persijn been away for quite a long time, let me write atleast a few now :D

Comment: That's some of the way there, but I think that having to pass the styles like that will impose a really cumbersome syntax. But let me play around with it a bit.. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaFrank: I prefer the approach with passing rulesets but if you want to only generate a selector using the mixin then see the update to my answer. I was filling it out as I saw your comment :)

Comment: @Harry: So, when I tried your first example, I get compiler errors of `props` and in the latest version, I get errors on `sel`. I must be using a version of LESS that has different rules than your version. I'm not sure what else would explain it. Ugh.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank: I'm using the online compiler @ http://http://less2css.org/ and it runs on v2.5.3. Are you using some older version (or) a port of Less.js like LessPHP or dotLess etc?

Comment: It's the version that's bundled with WebCompiler for Visual Studio, so yes. Let me see about upgrading and then trying your code.

Comment: Ok @JoshuaFrank If upgrading doesn't work then tell me the version number and I'll see if I can tailor my answer to fit that version.